# MDB2 quotes -- null values?

Tags: php, null, pear, quote, mdb2

According to the PEAR MDB2 documentation, I can optionally quote or not quote values using the third parameter:

$mdb2->quote($val1, "text", true)
$mdb2->quote($val2, "integer", false)

Is there a way to enable conversion of blank values to NULL?  Ie, if $val1 were empty or actually null, it would appear as NULL in the insert/update statement (instead of '').

Comment: please add that as an answer or close the question.

Comment: For integers, the solution is to check the value prior to applying $mdb2->quote. If the value is '', then set it to null.

The same technique does not work with strings (text) however.  Empty text strings converted to null ($textvalue = null) are rendered back to empty strings by **quote**.

Comment: It's not allowing me to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "a coder" does not have enough reputation to answer, I'm adding his answer to get the question from the unanswered list:

---

For integers, the solution is to check the value prior to applying $mdb2->quote. If the value is '', then set it to null. The same technique does not work with strings (text) however. Empty text strings converted to null ($textvalue = null) are rendered back to empty strings by

Comment: Thanks "cweiske" -- preciate it.